# how can i running site on 3 languages in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have the site running on 3 languages, my component should be able to show translated items of my component

```
realestates

--realestate(items) - en-EN
--realestate(items) - de-DE
--realestate(items) - fa-FA
```

Would a good workaround be to extend my items table with a column translation which keeps the translation language code and each time the query would take this into consideration? For example:

```
select * item from realestets where translation = 'en-EN'
```

or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try following the same procedure Joomla is using for multilingual content. components/com_content/helpers/association.php might be a good starting point.

Joomla adds associations in the #__associations - table, where you can look up items with a multilingual counterpart.